# Excluding some classes from the cobertura report doesn't work

Tags: code-coverage, cobertura

I tried to exclude some classes from cobertura using:

```
<cobertura-instrument todir="${voldemort.instrumented.dir}" datafile="${cobertura.instrument.file}">
    <classpath refid="tools-classpath" />
                <ignore regex=".*\.xsd" />
                <fileset dir="${voldemort.dist.dir}/classes">
                    <include name="**/*.class" />
                    <exclude name="**/client/protocol/pb/*.class"/>
                    <exclude name="**/server/http/*.class"/>
            </fileset>
        </cobertura-instrument>
```

**However, that doesn't work**. I don't know where the problem is. Could you help me?

Answer (score 0):

You must do it like this:

```
<cobertura-instrument todir="${voldemort.instrumented.dir}" datafile="${cobertura.instrument.file}">
    <classpath refid="tools-classpath" />
    <ignore regex=".*\.xsd" />
    <fileset dir="${voldemort.dist.dir}/classes">
        <include name="**/*.class" />
    </fileset>

    <fileset dir="${voldemort.dist.dir}/classes">
        <exclude name="**/client/protocol/pb/*.class"/>
    </fileset>

    <fileset dir="${voldemort.dist.dir}/classes">
        <exclude name="**/server/http/*.class"/>
   </fileset>
</cobertura-instrument>
```